# WordPress Section of site will not Load Over SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I have been recently working on a new site for a small business named Stick'em Stickers.

Right now the site is set up so that the front end that the uses see is a static webpage. In the background I have a WordPress instance running that we use to load dynamic content onto our site.

For a better understanding, you can just visit the website [here](https://stickemstickers.net).

My problem is that any pages or content that is trying to load that are WordPress related, will not load correctly or all the way.

Comment: Two seconds in your browser's web developer console will reveal the issue. `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stickemstickers.net/wordpress/index.php/this-months-donation/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://stickemstickers.net/wordpress/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.e @ (index):15`

Comment: Wow, I have no idea why I didn't even think about that.

Comment: ~ relative urls are your friend. So is `get_bloginfo('url')`